# How to add custom add to quote button with display quantity of added product in magento?

Tags: magento-1.9

I wants to add "add to quote" button. after adding product in quote it will be display added product quantity in header. after viewing this list all product will be display in quote formate(like shopping cart). and it should be export as a pdf. please help.

Comment: For that you have to create a custom module. I think it will be hard to explain the entire thing here.

Comment: you can provide it on github share same link with me